# Excel CountIf IsFormula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to calculate the count of items in a range, that are a formula?

I'm only expecting `=TEXT` formulas, so I tried `=COUNTIF(1:1, "=TEXT")`, but that didn't work. Seems CountIf only operates with the displayed values of the cells.

Comment: Try find() and check for "=". As the first character, may need to consider left().

Comment: Have you tried `=SUM(--ISFORMULA(1:1))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(--ISFORMULA(1:1))` (for prior 365)?

Comment: One more alternative approach, I am posting in comments and not in answers for some obvious reasons, will do once confirmed its working for you, as for this you need to be in MS365 current channel  `=REDUCE(0,LEFT(FORMULATEXT(D6:D19),6)="=TEXT(",LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(N(VSTACK(x,IFNA(y,0))))))`

Comment: Perhaps, we can exclude the `VSTACK()` as well, `=REDUCE(0,LEFT(FORMULATEXT(D6:D19),6)="=TEXT(",LAMBDA(x,y,SUM(x,N(IFNA(y,0)))))`

Comment: Josh, (a) you are correct that conditional logic (like COUNTIF) looks at the cell value.  But also (b) functions like MATCH COUNTIF, etc only match the *entire* cell.  So a formula in B1 like `=TEXT(A1)` would result in the condition `B1="Text"` returning FALSE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I have understood your post clearly, specifically you need those functions which starts `TEXT()` then perhaps you could try :

[image]

• Formula used in cell `F6`

```
=SUM(N(IFERROR(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(D6:D19),6)="=TEXT(",0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following in cells `A1:A5`

```
=TEXT("493","DDD")
555
=TEXT("420000","YYYY")
Yep
Nope
```

Either of these formulas should give a result of  `2`

Counts formulas

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISFORMULA(A:A))
```

Counts Cells with Formula `Text`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("text(",FORMULATEXT(A:A))))
```